# Programmatically halt -webkit-overflow-scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, scroll

I have a phonegap application that uses iOS native scrolling through `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` in a div. I want to be able to manually halt an ongoing scroll when the user clicks a button (to scroll back to the top of the page). Is this doable?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually very possible when using [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick). The lib removes the 300ms click delay on mobile devices and enables event capturing during inertia/momentum scrolling.

After including fastclick and attaching it to the body element, my code to stop scrolling and go to the top looks like this:

```
scrollElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
scrollElement.scrollTop = 0;
setTimeout(function() {
  scrollElement.style.overflow = '';
}, 10);
```

The trick is to set `overflow: hidden`, which stops the inertia/momentum scrolling. Please see my fiddle for a full implementation of [stop scrolling during inertia/momentum](http://jsfiddle.net/6EYxz/).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment. The `scroll` event is triggered only when the scrolling has come to an end. As long as the momentum keeps moving the content *no* events are fired at all. You can see this in [Figure 6-1 The panning gesture](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) in Apple's "*Safari Web Content Guide*".

I also created a [fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/F9kMR/) this behavior. The `scrollTop` value is set *after* iOS is done animating.

Comment: I tested iOS 6.1 and 7.1 Mobile Safari and found that the `scroll` event fires during the momentum scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a touch event using 'touchstart' instead of 'click', as the click event sometimes doesn't seem to get fired until the momentum scroll completes.  Try this jQuery solution:

```
$('#yourTrigger').on('touchstart', function () {
    var $div = $('.yourScrollableDiv');
    if ($div.scrollTop() === 0) {
        return false; //if no scroll needed, do nothing.
    }
    $div.addClass('scrolling'); //apply the overflow:hidden style with a class
    $div.animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 600, function () {
        $div.removeClass('scrolling'); //scrolling has finished, remove overflow:hidden
    });
}
```

where the 'scrolling' class simply has the CSS property, overflow:hidden, which as @Patrick-Rudolph said, will halt any momentum scrolling in progress.

```
.scrolling {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Note: It's best to use a callback function to tell when your scroll animation finishes, rather than setting a timer function.