# force-stop momentum scrolling on iphone/ipad in javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, infinite-scroll, momentum

Is it possible to force-stop momentum scrolling on iphone/ipad in javascript?

Extra: pretty sure this is pie in the sky, but for bonuspoints (honor and kudos), after dom-manipulation and a scrollTo applied, resume scroll with the same momentum before the forced stop. How to?

Comment: Have you tried setting the scroll position and disabling overflow on the body/html? Resuming the scroll could also be possible, look at the scroll events prior to stopping and calculate your `dy`. You will need to get a good estimate for a value of the _friction_ though (how quickly it slows down).

Comment: If I got your question right I think I answered it here: [Programatically halt -webkit-overflow-scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770891/programatically-halt-webkit-overflow-scrolling/14771980#14771980)

Comment: OK guys thanks.Trying how realiable it is to get the last `dy` and go from there.

Comment: yeah so indeed as @insertusernamehere suggested `scrolltop`  is only available after scroll has stopped. I need this as indicator to start with to forcestop the scroller, so it doesn't seem possible. hmm. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 13):

This is actually very possible when using [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick). The lib removes the 300ms click delay on mobile devices and enables event capturing during inertia/momentum scrolling.

After including fastclick and attaching it to the body element, my code to stop scrolling and go to the top looks like this:

```
scrollElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
scrollElement.scrollTop = 0;
setTimeout(function() {
  scrollElement.style.overflow = '';
}, 10);
```

The trick is to set `overflow: hidden`, which stops the inertia/momentum scrolling. Please see my fiddle for a full implementation of [stop scrolling during inertia/momentum](http://jsfiddle.net/6EYxz/).

Comment: Resetting the overflow to hidden, then back to auto or scroll is a solid solution without using fastclick.js.  Just don't forget the timeout!

Comment: This is the first answer I've found that's simple and works cross-browser. Note that `timeOut` cannot be set to `0`

Comment: Setting `overflow: hidden` will make scroll in UI unresponsive.

Comment: I figured this out except without fastclick.js. Problem is I'm trying to scroll to a certain position _and_ cancel the momentum, and this way prevents the scroll from animating, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code using jQuery animation (running as onclick event)

```
var obj=$('html, body'); // your element

if(!obj.is(':animated')) {

    obj.css('overflow', 'hidden').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, function(){ obj.css('overflow', ''); });

}
```

Tested on iPhone 6

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to CANCEL the BODY momentum scrolling by assigning the **html.scrollTop** property on **touchend** event. Looks like this:

```
let html = document.querySelector('html');
window.addEventListener( 'touchend', function( e ){
    html.scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
});
```

Tested on iOS 13

**UPD: The above solution fails on iOS 12**, because the actual scrolling element is not "html" in this version.

The below code works for Both 12 & 13:

```
window.addEventListener( 'touchend', function( e ){
    window.scroll( 0, window.scrollY );
});
```