# iOS: -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch and scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, scroll, momentum

I have some trouble when trying to back to the top of a list.

I put `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` on the list to get momentum scroll. 
However when I'm using jQuery `scrollTop();` while the momentum scroll is still going, it jumps to the top but it doesn't stop the momentum. So it keeps going down again until the momentum ends.

Is there an easy way to stop momentum scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your list's `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` style to `'auto'` and then back to `'touch'` after a short timeout.

i.e.

```
let scrollContainer = document.getElementById('yourListId');

scrollContainer.style['-webkit-overflow-scrolling'] = 'auto';  // stop scroll

setTimeout(function() {
       scrollContainer.scrollTop = 0;  // or jQuery scrollTop()
       scrollContainer.style['-webkit-overflow-scrolling'] = 'touch'; // re-enable
}, 2);
```

Reference: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109561/force-stop-momentum-scrolling-on-iphone-ipad-in-javascript). (modified their implementation to get rid of scrollbar redraw jerkiness on desktop browsers)